# Under what further hypotheses $A$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I am studying something about definite positive matrices from the book "applied numerical linear algebra" of Demmel. In particular, I am trying to understand under what hypotheses, it is possible to converse this implication:
[image]

I mean, if all $a_{ii}>0$ and $\max_{ij}|a_{ij}| =\max_i a_{ii} >0$ under what further hypotheses on the matrix $A$, we can conclude that it is definite positive. It happens surely when the matrix is diagonal, but in what further cases?

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Controlling the magnitude of the coefficients won't prevent the matrix from becoming singular, so you have to include $\det A \neq 0$ into your conditions. To make things easier, first look at symmetric matrices. Check it in the $2\times 2$ case, have a look at Sylvesters's criterion, see whether you'll get an answer like that ...

Comment: A slightly more general topic is "diagonal dominance". A symmetric diagonally dominant matrix with positive diagonal entries is positive definitive. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix